# $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ - Orthogonal circles?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Show that the circles of equations $u(x,y)=a$ and $v(x,y)=b$ ($a\not=0$,$b \not=0$, constants) are orthogonal curves.

One has $$\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{x+iy} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} +i \,\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}.$$ Hence $u(x,y) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $v(x,y)=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}.$ The equation $u(x,y)=a$ gives $$ax^2+ay^2-x = 0.$$ Completing the square, I got $$\left(x-\frac{1}{2a}\right)^2+y^2 = \left(\frac{1}{2a}\right)^2.$$

The second equation is $x^2+(y+\frac{1}{2b})=(\frac{1}{2b})^2$

I dont know how to continue this problem. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: The level curves of $u$ are orthogonal to the level curves of $v$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685543/intersections-of-the-level-curves-of-two-conjugate-harmonic-functions/1685617#1685617).

Comment: @IvoTerek So it is necessary to parameter each of the circles?

Comment: No. Why would it be? We need only notice that $\nabla u$ and $\nabla v$ are orthogonal.

Comment: As I understand, since $u$ and $v$ are constants, so $<\nabla u,\nabla v>=0$? Why does it gives the informations $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$?

Comment: They give you a concrete expression for $f$ because probably they expect you to carry the computations for this case, not realizing that the result I mentioned above is true. $u$ and $v$ are not constants, $\langle \nabla u, \nabla v\rangle = 0$ follow from the Cauchy-Riemann equations